# Angularjs conditionally switch part of view when variable becomes available

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have following issue. I want to be able to change part of my view when variable becomes available how can I do that ? I have tried `ng-switch` and `ng-if` but I am missing something. Here is the following code.

> HTML

```html
<div class="form-row">
   <p class="total__price-p">Total: <strong ng-if="selectedPrice" 
   class="total__price">
    [[selectedPrice | currency : currSign : 2]]</strong></p>
</div>
```

Fore example lets say I have another variable `discounted` that gets initialized later on and I want that variable to replace current how can I do that ?

***Update: I have managed to swap the values like so.***

```html
<div class="form-row">
   <p ng-if="totalx == undefined" class="total__price-p">Total: <strong ng-if="selectedPrice && totalx == undefined" class="total__price">
      [[selectedPrice | currency : currSign : 2]]</strong>
   </p>
   <p ng-if="totalx !== undefined" class="total__price-p">Total: <strong class="total__price">
      [[totalx | currency : currSign : 2]]</strong>
   </p>
</div>
```

But when I go and change the `selectedPrice` `discounted` should apply on new price.

Comment: Its preference you can set it both ways.

Comment: angular uses curly braces not square brackets. what exactly are you trying to do? are you trying to add the `strong` tag when the selectedPrice is populated?

Comment: As i said it is a preference, I'm trying to swap value of  `selectedPrice` with value of  `discount` once `discount` and if it gets initialized.

Comment: just assign discount to selectedPrice